# 1100.5.4.1 Unauthorized Pop-Up Window. Outlook Office.context.auth.getAccessTokenAsync shows authentication popup

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

We are working on a Microsoft Outlook add-in which utilizes SSO as well as fallback method for authentication. Our add-in has failed the validation policy twice in the store with following error

**Customer Control
1100.5.4.1 Unauthorized Pop-Up Window
Apps and add-ins may only open pop-up windows when triggered by explicit user interaction.**

After a tedious debugging we were able to recreate this in our environment **on incognito mode in chrome/edge and when third party cookie is blocked in Incognito.**

We have observed that OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken does not throw any error for the first time add-in is activated and directly prompt for authentication in a popup. We also tried to suppress the popup by adding options as described in the articles below but there were no changes in popup behavior.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-NodeJS-SSO/blob/master/Complete/public/javascripts/ssoAuthES6.js

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-runtime/officeruntime.authoptions?view=excel-js-preview

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins.md

Our adding is build with vue.js and uses following lib.

https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js

https://unpkg.com/@microsoft/office-js-helpers@1.0.2/dist/office.helpers.min.js

Although we are not sure if validation team is testing in incognito mode or with third party cookie disabled option. **There are no detail info given to recreate this issue in the validation failure document which is very frustrating. We have also open a support ticket 2104060010001500 and unfortunately that did not help.**

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Ack. We are trying to understand this issue. We will get back to you shortly.

Comment: We checked internally and found that your addin is now published successfully after you recently submitted again. We consider this is not a problem you anymore. Let us know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Our app is live however for now reason it was under discussion for a month. Also, there is no answer to what happened to popup issue. Anyway, thank you for your response. !